# At the time of deallocation

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic, new-operator, allocation

Here i am doing dynamic memory allocation .But problem is that after deleting memory, the data is not removing from that block.Only first two blocks are deleting.
Why ?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <new>
 using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int i,n;
  int * p;
  cout << "How many numbers would you like to type? ";
  cin >> i;
  p= new (nothrow) int[i];
  if (p == 0)
    cout << "Error: memory could not be allocated";
  else
  {
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
    {
      cout << "Enter number: ";
      cin >> p[n];
    }
    cout << "You have entered: ";
    for (n=0; n<i; n++)
      cout <<"Value= "<< p[n] << ",Address = "<<&p[n]<<endl;
    delete p;
    cout<<endl<<"After Deallocation"<<endl;
  for (n=0; n<i; n++)
      cout <<"Value= " <<p[n] << ",Address = "<<&p[n]<<endl;
}
  return 0;
}
```

[image: Output of Code]

Comment: *Only first two blocks are deleting* -- What is your definition of "deleting"?  The memory isn't going to just disappear into a puff of smoke.  There will be remnants of something left at those locations, and you can't determine what those remnants mean by mere inspection.

Comment: BTW for deleting an array, you should call `delete[] p`.

Comment: i also used it but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The data is deallocated, but it doesn't mean that the data values were changed.

How the data is going to be changed is not specfied. The memory may be reallocated a nanosecond after the deallocation and completely changed. Or it can stay the same until your computer stops.

Comment: is there any way to check that memory has been deallocate? or how to check how many memory used in x function?

Comment: No, no way of checking if it's still allocated or valid, it's part of the contract of an API. Then if you want to know how much memory is used by a function (which is completely another question), then you can use massif or heaptrack.